# select2 doesnt show data

Tags: jquery-select2, nette

I need to use multiselect so I got idea use select2 tags for that. But I got a problem.. I have rendered multiselect from nette with values.. when I look on html code I can see all options with their values.. but when I enable select2 for that select it says 'No results found' but still in code there are data.. also I wanted to use tags, and also this is not working either .. Any possible solutions guys? Thanks

I'm enabling select2 like this - that select has class 'multiple-regions':

```html
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.multiple-regions').select2({
                tags: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

PS: I have included jquery before bootstrap and select2 includes.

EDIT: posting HTML (I'm now using form component from nette but it's same when I use raw HTML)

```html
{form filterRoutesForm}
  <div class="row" style="padding: 0 1em;">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        {label date class=>"form-control-label"/}
        {input date class=>"form-control daterange-routes"}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        {label region class=>"form-control-label"/}
        {input region class=>"form-control multiple-regions"}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      {input search class=>"btn btn-primary form-control", style=>"margin-top: 35px;"}
    </div>
  </div>
{/form}
```

Here is same example with raw HTML:

```html
<select name="region[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control multiple-regions">
  <option value="all">všechny kraje</option>
  <option value="1">Praha</option>
  <option value="2">Střední Čechy</option>
  <option value="3">Jih a západ Čech</option>
  <option value="4">Severní Čechy</option>
  <option value="5">Východní Čechy</option>
  <option value="6">Jižní Morava</option>
  <option value="7">Severní Morava</option>
  <option value="8">Bratislava</option>
  <option value="9">Západní Slovensko</option>
  <option value="0">Východní Slovensko</option>
</select>
```

BTW also I have tried added data as array in 'data' property in select2, but still same effect - No results found

Comment: post your html code as well.

Comment: Edited post - 2 examples of code how I have tried to do this

Comment: I think that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As your question doesn't seem to be caused by the `select2` plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days for rest I solved it.. Problem was in external .js file - where my colleague defined .select2 style which select2 uses defaulty .. So when I wanted to declare select2 in script his style rewrited it and then it hasn`t data.. Thank you for everything. Cya

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `select2.css`, `select2.js` as well as `jquery` if that's not already done, add `multiple` and that's pretty much all you need.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.multiple-regions').select2({
      tags: true,
      width: '100%'
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.css" />

<select name="region[]" class="form-control multiple-regions" multiple>
  <option value="all">všechny kraje</option>
  <option value="1">Praha</option>
  <option value="2">Střední Čechy</option>
  <option value="3">Jih a západ Čech</option>
  <option value="4">Severní Čechy</option>
  <option value="5">Východní Čechy</option>
  <option value="6">Jižní Morava</option>
  <option value="7">Severní Morava</option>
  <option value="8">Bratislava</option>
  <option value="9">Západní Slovensko</option>
  <option value="0">Východní Slovensko</option>
</select>
```

You could eventually add, if needed, `closeOnSelect: false` as a `select2` argument to prevent it from closing on each select, it's useful for multiple selections.

Comment: Sorry I probably wrote it wrong, Im including select2.js and select2.css after jquery. That was the right meaning of 'I have included jquery before bootstrap and select2'. Your answer does still no result effect :/

Comment: Then you didn't quite well explain your problem, I can't guess where your problem is coming from :) A multiple select2 works fine with the code you shared as seen in my example.

Comment: That's pretty weird, I have copypasted your code to my .latte file and still nothing.. select2 is drawed but with no data and when I inspect code I can see my select with data there :/ I think somehow select2 render select with no data but Im confused when I can see my data in select2 when I inspect loaded page..

Comment: @OndraKovács Is the extension of your file `file.latte`? Because if you make a test.html file and copy paste this code, it WILL work : https://jsfiddle.net/h79prLkj/

Comment: Yes In my .latte file I have multile other things but this is in alone div - its not in some snippet or things like that

Comment: @OndraKovács make sure, in the rendered page, that it's the correct html and javascript and that they are, obviously, in the same page.